# How can I upsert a record and array element at the same time?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, event-sourcing

That is meant to be read as a dual upsert operation, upsert the document then the array element.

So MongoDB is a denormalized store for me (we're event sourced) and one of the things I'm trying to deal with is the concurrent nature of that. The problem is this:

- Events can come in out of order, so each update to the database need to be an upsert.
- I need to be able to not only upsert the parent document but an element in an array property of that document.

For example:

- If the document doesn't exist, create it. All events in this stream have the document's ID but only part of the information depending on the event.
- If the document does exist, then update it. This is the easy part. The update command is just written as UpdateOneAsync and as an upsert.
- If the event is actually to update a list, then that list element needs to be upserted. So if the document doesn't exist, it needs to be created and the list item will be upserted (resulting in an insert); if the document does exist, then we need to find the element and update it as an upsert, so if the element exists then it is updated otherwise it is inserted.

If at all possible, having it execute as a single atomic operation would be ideal, but if it can only be done in multiple steps, then so be it. I'm getting a number of mixed examples on the net due to the large change in the 2.x driver. Not sure what I'm looking for beyond the UpdateOneAsync. Currently using 2.4.x. Explained examples would be appreciated. TIA

Note:
Reiterating that this is a question regarding the MongoDB C# driver 2.4.x

Comment: @neillunn RE: Duplicate question: This is tagged with mongocsharpdriver and mentions the driver version in the post. That other answer is mongo cli. I will update post to be more clear about that.

Comment: I'll see if I can't grok the theory behind it and apply it to the C# driver usage, but I'm just pointing out that this isn't a dupe.

Comment: If you see the theory then you should understand why it's a duplicate. The process actually requires multiple operations and there is no other way. In particular you basically cannot choose whether to append to an array and "upsert" at the same time, because negative tests on an array result in an "upsert" every time, when your intent is to add to the array. So the answer is use the multiple operations and use `builkWrite()` to do them. Which is what is already covered. The only thing left here is do you want to be the guy how is asking someone else to write out all the C# code?

Comment: I agree, but the C# driver implements a pretty complex interface which is part of the question "how do i do this with the C# driver." It isn't a question whether or not I want someone to write the code for me so much as it is about not knowing what threads to pull on with this particular version of the driver. It's incredibly aggravating when people bat the question down under that assumption. I don't know what I don't know. Productive answer might be to reference that other post and then talk through how the C# driver accomplishes this as it is not as obvious to some that are new to it.

Comment: And this shouldn't be about whether or not you feel that I should be able to answer my own question about the C# driver by understanding how one would do it in the mongo CLI, it's about whether or not that makes it a duplicate question which it does not.

Comment: Actually it's about the author of the material that already adequately explains what you need to do here. Perhaps you should be acknowledging the worth and accuracy of the existing work.  You have a single `bulkWrite()` to issue with three `UpdateOneModel` operations laid out exactly as described in the linked answers. Nothing complex about it.

Comment: I'm not understanding the driver interface, Neil. I am googling trying to find a complete example of even using it but everything I've come across seems to skip at least half the steps involved in even creating the models that perform those 3 steps. In other words, I want to use your article, but plugging it into the C# driver is proving to be a challenge.

Comment: In particular, the second statement "push element where a: 1 does not exist". I'm having trouble figuring out how to write that using the driver interface. It's easy to write it for "where this DOES match" but not where does not match...

Comment: This question is definitely not a duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

Took some tinkering, but I got it.

```
var notificationData = new NotificationData
{
    ReferenceId = e.ReferenceId,
    NotificationId = e.NotificationId,
    DeliveredDateUtc = e.SentDate.DateTime
};

var matchDocument = Builders<SurveyData>.Filter.Eq(s => s.SurveyId, e.EntityId);

// first upsert the document to make sure that you have a collection to write to
var surveyUpsert = new UpdateOneModel<SurveyData>(
    matchDocument,
    Builders<SurveyData>.Update
        .SetOnInsert(f => f.SurveyId, e.EntityId)
        .SetOnInsert(f => f.Notifications, new List<NotificationData>())){ IsUpsert = true};

// then push a new element if none of the existing elements match
var noMatchReferenceId = Builders<SurveyData>.Filter
    .Not(Builders<SurveyData>.Filter.ElemMatch(s => s.Notifications, n => n.ReferenceId.Equals(e.ReferenceId)));

var insertNewNotification = new UpdateOneModel<SurveyData>(
    matchDocument & noMatchReferenceId,
    Builders<SurveyData>.Update
        .Push(s => s.Notifications, notificationData));

// then update the element that does match the reference ID (if any)
var matchReferenceId = Builders<SurveyData>.Filter
    .ElemMatch(s => s.Notifications, Builders<NotificationData>.Filter.Eq(n => n.ReferenceId, notificationData.ReferenceId));
var updateExistingNotification = new UpdateOneModel<SurveyData>(
    matchDocument & matchReferenceId,
    Builders<SurveyData>.Update 
        // apparently the mongo C# driver will convert any negative index into an index symbol ('$')
        .Set(s => s.Notifications[-1].NotificationId, e.NotificationId)
        .Set(s => s.Notifications[-1].DeliveredDateUtc, notificationData.DeliveredDateUtc));

// execute these as a batch and in order
var result = await _surveyRepository.DatabaseCollection
    .BulkWriteAsync(
        new []{ surveyUpsert, insertNewNotification, updateExistingNotification }, 
        new BulkWriteOptions { IsOrdered = true })
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The post linked as being a dupe was absolutely helpful, but it was not the answer. There were a few things that needed to be discovered.

- The 'second statement' in the linked example didn't work
  correctly, at least when translated literally. To get it to work, I had to match on the
  element and then invert the logic by wrapping it in the Not() filter.
- In order to use 'this index' on the match, you have to use a
  negative index on the array. As it turns out, the C# driver will
  convert any negative index to the '$' character when the query is
  rendered.
- In order to ensure they are run in order, you must include bulk write
  options with `IsOrdered` set to true.